# Unable to Parse JSON with Delphi

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a JSON string which comes from Amazon. (https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/index.json)  The top of the JSON looks like this...
[image]

I need to retrieve a list of JUST the offerCode and versionIndexUrl values. I can read an array of offers, but the key of each offer is different, so I can't use the NAME(comprehend, AmazonMWAA, etc).   I have tried using element [0] but I get an AV.  Here is my relevant code...

```
procedure Load_AWS_Services;
  var 
  json: string;
  idx: Integer;
  obj: TJSONObject;
  j_array: TJSONArray; // the array of all lineitems/offers
  lineItem : TJSONObject;
  ServiceEntry: TJSONPair;

  begin
  try
    
     JSON :=  DownloadFromURLasString('https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/index.json');
     obj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSON) as TJSONObject;
     
     try
       // Now parse the data...
       j_array := TJSONArray(obj.Get('offers').JsonValue);
       
       // Now loop through each individual item
       for idx := 0 to pred(j_array.size) do
       begin
      
         lineItem := TJSONObject(j_array.Get(idx));
         Main.Memo1.Lines.Add(lineItem.ToString);  // this shows each offer...so good to this point
        ServiceEntry := lineItem.Pairs[0];
        ShowMessage(ServiceEntry.Value);  // AV here
```

What do I need to change in my last 2 lines to read INSIDE the 'offers'?

Comment: *'Unable to Parse JSON with Delphi'* - that is completely false statement. You obviously are able to parse the JSON received from AWS.

Comment: @PeterWolf - If I am not able to get the element I am trying to get, then I am not able to properly parse...

Comment: You're not able to properly **access** the values in parsed JSON. The answer indicates why.

Comment: Please do not post images to represent textual data. Images can't be copied and pasted for use iin helping find a solution, they're unreadable from mobile devices, and they're unfriendly to screen readers. Post text as text and properly format it for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `offers` field is a JSON object, not a JSON array (had you used the `as` operator for the `TJSONArray` cast, you would have gotten an `EInvalidCast` exception raised).

Try this instead:

```pascal
procedure Load_AWS_Services;
var 
  json: string;
  idx: Integer;
  j_val: TJSONValue;
  j_obj: TJSONObject;
  j_pair: TJSONPair;
  offers: TJSONObject;
  lineItem : TJSONObject;
begin
  try
    json := DownloadFromURLasString('https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/index.json');
    j_val := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(json);
    try
      j_obj := j_val as TJSONObject;

      // Now parse the data...
      offers := j_obj.GetValue('offers') as TJSONObject;
       
      // Now loop through each individual item
      for idx := 0 to pred(offers.Count) do
      begin
        j_pair := offers.Get(idx);
        Main.Memo1.Lines.Add(j_pair.JsonString.Value);
        lineItem := j_pair.JsonValue as TJSONObject;
        ShowMessage(lineItem.GetValue('offerCode').Value);
        ShowMessage(lineItem.GetValue('versionIndexUrl').Value);
        ...
      end;
    finally
      j_val.Free;
    end;
  except
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Awesome... this worked great.. Thank you!